# Apache 2.4 custom logs exception

Tags: linux, configuration, apache-2.4, log-files

i am trying to clean my apache log, so i try to seprate trafic / bot / stats in 3 differents files

i used the doc : http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/logs.html

```
# [ Logs Exeptions ]
# - Exeption
SetEnvIf Request_URI "\.jpg$|\.jpeg$|\.gif$|\.png$|\.ico|\.icon|\.css$|\.js$|piwik\.php$|frogglogin\.php" dontlog
SetEnvIf User-agent "bot|baidu" dontlog
# - Special rules
SetEnvIf User-agent "bot|baidu" botlog
SetEnvIf Request_URI "piwik\.php$" piwiklog
# - Custom log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/bot.log combined env=botlog
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/piwik.log combined env=piwiklog
# - logs 
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined env=!dontlog
```

acces.log is correct, there is only accessed files, but bot & piwik log are empty !
i tried common instead of combined but with the same result...
(apache has been restarted)

can someone explain me what i did wrong ?

Thanks

Comment: no one know what is wrong ? :'(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CustomLog may be used in the following contexts: server config, virtual host

so i needed to set CustomLog instruction in  tag

or change combined by vhost_combined